# How much bytes a kilobyte?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Are we using [binary](https://superuser.com/q/277600/101850) or [decimal](https://superuser.com/q/143584/101850) units on Super User? I have seen questions using both „conventions”.

(Please don’t tell me we’re using [decimal during leap years and binary otherwise](http://xkcd.com/394/).)

Comment: I have to just say: Who really cares? It's a little number, it's not the end of the internet as we know it.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think we should act here and enforce one or the other.

Considering the relative obscurity of binary prefixes (e.g. *KiB* for 1024 byte), and the fact that e.g. Windows uses the SI prefixes but means multiples of 1024, it wouldn't actually help any.

Most users should be aware of there being a problem in the definition and use of these prefixes, because they've been "cheated" out of 7% of the disk space they've bought (a 1 TB disk has 931 "GB").

There's bound to be some misunderstanding, but it's the same for the entire IT industry. It's something we'll just have to live with for a while.

Comment: Still explicitness about units can be encouraged when it is relevant.

Comment: @N.N. Sure, but we can prompt users to clarify on a case by case basis. There's no reason to go around and edit all those topics.

Comment: The fact is, in all posts I've read, there has never been any problem of misunderstanding because of (improperly used) binary or decimal notation. If a topic is specifically about the difference between these two, then of course it's different.